# Default value for ansible hosts in playbook?

Tags: ansible

My sample playbook (for ansible 2.1) is:

```
---
# This is sample playbook.

- name: add sample_role
  hosts: '{{ target }}'
  become: true
  become_user: root
  roles:
    - sample role
```

When i run it, everything is fine:

```
ansible-playbook -i staging test_playbook.yml --extra-vars "target=192.168.15.29"
```

How can i omit targets?

I've tried something like this:

```
  hosts: '{{ target | default(all) }}'
```

or

```
  hosts: '{{ target | default(hostvars) }}'
```

then run:

```
ansible-playbook -i staging test_playbook.yml
```

, but unfortunately:

> ERROR! 'all' is undefined

or:

> ERROR! 'hostvars' is undefined

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you simply add the `all` without quote then it take it as variable, so you can fixed it like this:

`hosts: '{{ target | default("all") }}'`

As far `hostvars` it's a reserved word in ansible and can't use it for this purpose I think. It's value will be something like this:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "localhost": {
            "ansible_check_mode": false,
            "ansible_version": {
                "full": "2.1.0.0",
                "major": 2,
                "minor": 1,
                "revision": 0,
                "string": "2.1.0.0"
            },
            "group_names": [],
            "groups": {
                "all": [
                    "localhost"
                ],
                "ungrouped": []
            },
            "inventory_dir": null,
            "inventory_file": null,
            "inventory_hostname": "localhost",
            "inventory_hostname_short": "localhost",
            "omit": "__omit_place_holder__41c600ef78930ed8b38e6eed4e5b5ab51199729e",
            "playbook_dir": "/Users/xyz/test-ansible"
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that help you.

Comment: Double quotes around `all` works for me: ````hosts: '{{ target | default("all") }}'````

Comment: Why does `'{{ target | default("all") }}'` work?  In particular, why does the `|` symbol work? Where is this documented?  I have a use-case where I would like to set multiple default groups as targets.